# How to send data using button from Java (desktop application) to JavaScript (web interface) using jetty websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I am new to web socket, and I am having hard time with sending of message. I want my queue status to send and display in the web interface using jetty web socket. and I already have the jettyserver, jettywebsocketclientendpoint, jettywebsocketserverendpoint

here is the code for queue management.

```
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                numberQueue++;
                updateNumber(); 
                playNextTrack();
            }
        });
        

        prevButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (numberQueue > 0) {
                    numberQueue--;
                    updateNumber();
                }
                playPreviousTrack();
            }

        });
```

and here is the code for the updateNumber.

```
protected void updateNumber() {
        numberLabel.setText(String.valueOf(numberQueue));
        QueueWebSocketClient.sendMessageToServer("Queue updated: " + numberQueue);
        WebSocketServerEndpoint.broadcastMessage("Queue updated: " + numberQueue);
        System.out.println("Queue updated: " + numberQueue);
    }
```